# jQuery - .hover() change back img when not hover = wrong img

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I have a list of productimages with two different images on each product. First one shows when not hovering over the image and second one shows when hovering over the image.

The problem is that if I go from hovering over one productimage and fast over to another one, then the first productimage gets the second products firstimage, so wrong productimage.

The code looks something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="listing">
 <ul>
  <li data-artnr="3212" class="product"> 
    <div class="image"> 
      <a href="/">
        <img src="/pathTo/image/3212.jpg" class="loaded">
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li data-artnr="3213" class="product"> 
    <div class="image"> 
      <a href="/">
        <img src="/pathTo/image/3213.jpg" class="loaded">
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li data-artnr="3214" class="product"> 
    <div class="image"> 
      <a href="/">
        <img src="/pathTo/image/3214.jpg" class="loaded">
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#listingContent").find(".product").hover(function () {
  $product = $(this);
  $image = $(this).find(".loaded");
  var artnr = $product.data("artnr");
  window.oldImage = $image.attr("src");
  var newImage = "/pathTo/image/"+artnr+"_topoffer.jpg";
  $product.data("old", oldImage);

  $image.fadeOut(150, function () {
    $(this).load(function () {
      $(this).fadeIn(150);
    }).attr("src", newImage);
  });
},
function () {
  $image.fadeOut(150, function () {
    $(this).load(function () {
      $(this).fadeIn(150);
    }).attr("src", oldImage);
  });
});
```

I guess this have something to do with the fadeIn/fadeOut so that $(this) already changed before the fadeIn starts.
Is there a better way to do this to avoid this problem? The problem doesn't occure when I remove fadeIn/fadeOut but this is something I want to have since without it the transmition is to hard.

Comment: Hi it will be a great help if you can create the fiddle for issue, that way makes is easier for us to solve it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly note that your HTML is invalid. `li` elements can only be children of a `ul`, not a `div`.

The cause of your problem is because you use the global `oldImage` variable. It would be better to use the 'old' `data` attribute you store on the `.product` element so that there's no race condition when quickly hovering between elements. 
Also note that you don't need to re-bind the `load()` event on every `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`. You can place it on all required elements separately. Try this:

```js
$('#listingContent .product .loaded').load(function() {
  $(this).fadeIn(150);
});

$("#listingContent .product").hover(function() {
  var $product = $(this);
  var $image = $product.find(".loaded");
  var artnr = $product.data("artnr");  
  $product.data("old", $image.attr('src'));

  $image.fadeOut(150, function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "/pathTo/image/" + artnr + "_topoffer.jpg");
  });
}, function() {
  var $product = $(this);
  var $image = $product.find(".loaded");

  $image.fadeOut(150, function() {
    $(this).attr("src", $product.data('old'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the note about the ul, I changed a bit in the code removing some stuff that is not important for this issue and the ul went with it. It's edited now in the question.
About your solution, it seems to work, tho' now I get display: none as an inline style on the images. I am thinking this have something to do with some other plugin, possibly lazyload. I'll try figuring out what is causing this because from what I can tell in your answer it should not completly be because of this code, correct?

Comment: The inline `display: none` will be coming from the `fadeOut()`, although the `fadeIn()` should change that back again. It may be worth commenting out parts of the above to see when it is added.

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing

```
window.oldImage = $image.attr("src");
```

you should store oldImage in element itself i.e. in some attribute.

```
$product.data("old", $image.attr("src"));
```